# Responsive Web design In All Browsers using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hey i was using google chrome to write html, css, JS. CSS frame work i will use Bootstrap.
so i was tested on Chrome my code design how i am expect it works perfect and fine, when it comes to another browsers like Firefox and Opera, Internet Explorer, Safari it was not much expectedly work.
Like Box shadow and linear gradient some other.

i saw some CSS have -webkit, -o, -moz etc...

What are those means? and how i can learn them?

Kindly please tell how i can able to target css for particular browser like Opera and Firefox and safari.

```
-moz @media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* 
   Here i would like to target only firefox
*/
```

}

Comment: your question is too broad. what do you mean with i usign google chrome to write html etc etc? most of the css properties are cross browser, expecially bootstrap

Comment: @Sfili_81 i am clearly asked like: i saw some CSS have -webkit, -o, -moz etc...

What are those means? and how i can learn them?

Kindly please tell how i can able to target css for particular browser like Opera and Firefox and safari.

And my question is not too broad bro, i just using chrome for web development, and some of gradients and box shadows not working in another browser so how i am able to fix it, thats all i asked dude

Comment: You can also read the docs about it.  Just make a little search on google and you will find the solution. Before asking we expected you make some research about your problem. Consider to read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Some css properties are named depending on which browser is being used so we add what is called a prefix so its compatible with all of them. Let's see box shadow:

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

There are autoprefixers also!

Comment: Thanks bro, perfect answer i was looking for, so if i want to target Particular browser to execute my stylesheet means what i do for that?

Comment: You can check each property individually or use an autoprefixer such as https://autoprefixer.github.io which takes your code and automatically prefixes it